# Authentication in ReactJS using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I have a simple `route.js` file

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthed = localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
  return (
    <Route {...rest} exact
      render = {(props) => (
        isAuthed ? (
          <div>
            {React.createElement(component, props)}
          </div>
        ) :
        (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      )}
    />
  )
}
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('Authorization')) {
      history.push(`${history.location.pathname}`)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="App-pageContainer">
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />
          <Route path={'/login'} component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

What  I need is to put condition if the user has a key in localStorage(`Authentication`) then I want to redirect it to `/dashboard` if it doesn't contain `Authentication` in localStorage then I want to redirect it to `/login`.

I am totally stuck with this from past few days. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this kind of questions is too broad for an answer.

However, you could follow this amazing post to be able to implement that functionality.

[Protected routes and authentication with React Router v4](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/)

This is what you got after finishing

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}

const Public = () => <h3>Public</h3>
const Protected = () => <h3>Protected</h3>

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Login
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)

export default function AuthExample () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/public">Public Page</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/public" component={Public}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much  for the answer I will check let you know

Comment: You're welcome! Considering accept it in case it does help

Comment: What is `this.isAuthenticated` here and `cb`?

Comment: we are faking the authenticating process which will be implemented on the server-side. `isAuthenticated` is true means that the user is validated and vice versa. You can see the `cb` along with the `setTimeout(cb, 100)` method which pretending that you have to wait, let's say, 0,1s to receive the result from the server in the real life.

Comment: Final question It should not throw me on login page again if I do login once. Isn't it?

Comment: Well! Then you could use the `Json Web Token` for implementing that functionality, this article might help: https://blog.scalac.io/react-redux-jwt-authentication.html .